# How to create Vuejs controlled input form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, vue.js, controlled-component

I'm used to creating controlled components in react using state; however, I'm new to `Vue` and would like to learn how I could recreate my code from react into something Vue could use. I want the input fields values to be store in a piece of data so that I could do something with them.

```
<template>
    <form @submit="handleSubmit" class="form form--signin">
        <h2 class="form__h2">Log into your account</h2>

        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input v-model="email" type="email" id="email" autoComplete="off"/>

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input v-model="password" type="password" id="password" autoComplete="off"/>

        <button class="form__btn">Login</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
```

import axios from 'axios';

```
export default {
    name: 'SignIn',
    data() {
        return {
            user: null,
            email: null,
            password: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.login(this.email, this.password);
            this.email = '';
            this.password = '';
        },
        login(email, password) {
            axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/login', {
                email,
                password
            })
            .then(res => {
                // console.log(this.user);
                this.user = res.data.data.user;
                if(res.data.status === 'success') {
                    // setUserStatus(res.data.status);
                    window.setTimeout(() => {
                        window.location.assign('/');
                    }, 1500)
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.message));
        }
    }, 
    mounted() {
        if (!this.user) return;

        console.log('Writing to session storage...');
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, please. I'm trying to get data from the inputs such as the when the user types their email, password, name, passwordConfirm

Comment: I'm lost on how to do this is Vue

Comment: I'll update the code to show what I'm reading now but not quite understanding.

Comment: Could you explain the code I just edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it would look like in `Vue`

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const SignIn = Vue.component('sign-in', {

  template: `<form @submit="handleSubmit" className="form form--signin">
            <h2 className="form__h2">Log into your account</h2>

            <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
            <input v-model="email" type="email" id="email" autoComplete="off"/>

            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input v-model="password" type="password" id="password" autoComplete="off"/>

            <button className="form__btn">Login</button>
        </form>`,
  data() {
    return {
      user: null,
      email: null,
      password: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit(event) {

      this.login(this.email, this.password)
      this.email = '';
      this.password = '';
      
      event.preventDefault();
    },
    login(email, password) {

    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (!this.user)
      return;

    console.log('Writing to session storage...');
    sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <sign-in></sign-in>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll be sure to try to understand and implement it

Comment: I'm trying to get the user to = the response for the login function but nothing seems to work. I'm trying this.user = res.data.data.user

Comment: Yes it is defined

Comment: User stays as null

Comment: I believe that after login is run, it does not make user = to res.data immediately because its asynchronous but the code checks if user exists on mount. Is there a way to have the code check if user changed values sort of like in react with useEffect(() => {}, [user])?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I might approach writing the same component in Vue:

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit" class="form form--signin">
    <h2 class="form__h2">Log into your account</h2>

    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input v-model="email" type="email" id="email" autocomplete="off">

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input v-model="password" type="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">

    <button class="form__btn">Login</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
const login = async (email, password) => {
  // make the api call and return a promise
};

export default {
  name: "SignIn",
  data: () => ({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  }),
  methods: {
    async handleSubmit(event) {
      console.log("Getting user from API...");

      try {
        const user = await login(this.email, this.password);

        console.log("Writing to session storage...");
        sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));

        this.email = "";
        this.password = "";
      } catch (e) {
        // handle login errors
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The form controls' state is stored on the `data` property of the component, and a two-way binding is set up on the controls with the `v-model` directive. Any changes to the inputs will be synced to the component's state, and vice versa.

Vue provides some handy modifiers when adding event listeners to the template, so by writing `@submit.prevent` the default submit handler is prevented from firing.

I've created a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-solomon-jvl38?file=/src/components/SignIn.vue), so you can easily play around with the code and see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) directive to bind component data and [v-on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) directive to bind component methods:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class>Login Form</div>

    <form v-on:submit="handleSubmit">
      <input v-model="email" placeholder="email" type="text" class="input" />
      <br />
      <input v-model="password" placeholder="password" type="password" class="input" />
      <br />
      <button v-on:click="handleSubmit" type="submit" class="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

    <hr />

    <div>Email: {{email}} and Password: {{password}}</div>
    <div>User sessions: {{user}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make API call to authenticate and store `user` session data from response:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "LoginForm",
  props: {},
  data: () => ({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    user: {}
  }),
  methods: {
    login() {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/login", {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.user = res.data.data.user;
          sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(this.user));
          if (res.data.status === "success") {
            window.setTimeout(() => {
              window.location.assign("/"); // to verify mounted hook
            }, 1500);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.message));
    },
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.login();
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.debug("mounted");
  }
};
</script>
```

Also, note that you can use `mounted` [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) to read data from `localStorage` or any other of your choice.

You can use [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or then / catch to handle asynchronous (promise based) API calls.

Here is [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-login-form-3ovcg?file=/src/components/LoginForm.vue).

---

Here is how to use `mounted` hook same as `useEffect(() => {}, [])` in react:

```
mounted() {
    const user = sessionStorage.getItem("user");
    if (user) {
      this.user = JSON.parse(user);
    }
  }
```

Comment: the user is never being stored into session storage because it does not immediately equal the response from login because its async. When mounting happens, it it not yet equal to the response so mounted method returns and no user is stored. That is what I am currently stuck on. I could get around this in React with useEffect because it could run whenever the user value changed. But I need a Vue solution

Comment: I changed `login` method and added a note for `mounted` which uses `sessionStorage.getItem("user");`. Try now.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just got it working by setting the user data in session storage within the login method and it's working now